# Does Sprite Kit SKAction with time duration Slow Function Execution?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, updates, skaction

I have a function in my Sprite kit game where the game character dies and has a death animation. In this same method I set some attributes to let my update function know that the game is over so that the score can stop being incremented and some other things. But when this runs, the deathAnimation function seems to slow down the execution of the other variables that are being set. So the score keeps being incremented when it should stop for example. Why is this? is it something to do with my update function or does the animation with a time duration slow the entire method from being executed right away? 
Thanks for the help in advance!

Here is my deathAnimation method

```
func deathAnimation() {
    //set shield for death
    self.yourDead = true
    self.shield.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.maxX * 2, self.frame.maxY + self.ape.size.height * 10)
    self.shield.hidden = true
    self.shieldActivated = false
    //set Ape image to default
    self.ape.runAction(SKAction.setTexture(SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ape"), resize: true))
    self.ape.zRotation = 0
    //changes physicsBody values so He doesn't collide
    self.ape.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    self.ape.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Asteroid.rawValue
    self.ape.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Ape.rawValue
    self.ape.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Ape.rawValue
    self.ape.zPosition = 10     //bring the ape to the front
    let death = SKAction.sequence([
                        SKAction.group([
                                SKAction.scaleBy(4, duration: 0.5),
                                SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(self.frame.minX + ape.size.width * 2, self.frame.minY - ape.size.width * 2), duration: 2),
                                SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI_4), duration: 0.2), count: 8)
                            ]),
                        SKAction.runBlock({self.moveToGameOverView();})
                    ])
    ape.runAction(death)        //run the animation sequence
}
```

Here is my code where I check if the player is Dead or not and this is within the update function. I didn't include all of the update function because it is probably more than you would care to look at.

```
//take Asteroids off the screen and increment score
    enumerateChildNodesWithName("asteroid", usingBlock: {(node: SKNode!, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer <ObjCBool>) -> Void in
        //move the asteroids off the screen
        node.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x, node.position.y + self.gravity)
        //if it is out of screen
        if node.position.y > self.frame.size.height + self.largeAsteroid.size.width {
            node.removeFromParent()
            if !self.yourDead {         //if your not dead
                self.score++
                self.scoreText.text = String(self.score)
                //increase Asteroid speed
                if self.score > 20 * self.tensCounter {
                    self.gravity++
                    self.tensCounter++
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: I think it would help to see where you check `self.yourDead`. Also the fact that you run self.moveToGameOverView() at the same time you run scaleBy,moveTo, and repeatAction is fishy.

Comment: I edited my question to include where I use 'self.yourDead' . Also 'self.moveToGameOverView()' is not part of the group that the other actions are so it is ran after the animation so the game ends after the animation.

Comment: Yeah you are right about moveToGameOverView() I thought that it was grouped with those when I read it earlier but you are right they are in a sequence. I don't see any issues with what you posted unless you run the enumerateChildNodes before you runDeathAnimation the score should stop if that is the only place you increment it.

Comment: actually...are you preventing deathAnimation() from being called every loop? That would make things slow down for sure, but wouldn't explain the score issue.

Comment: Yeah `deathAnimation()` is only called when there is contact which means game over and if it did get called more than once than the `SKAction.scaleBy(4, duration: 0.5)` would make the Sprite huge which I think I would notice . Not sure why that doesn't stop the score from incrementing.

Comment: you were right! I was randomly incrementing the score somewhere else for some reason. Forgot that I was doing that. Thanks for the help! Not sure how I can give you points.

Comment: I provided an answer just because I think it could help others troubleshoot their problem if stumbling on this in their search for a solution. Good luck with your app =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code provided looks fine. However you could try checking a few things.

1. Make sure that you are not calling `deathAnimation()` over and over again.
2. Make sure you are not doing your `enumerateChildNodesWithName` before `deathAnimation()`.
3. Make sure you aren't incrementing the score somewhere else.

Those are the only reasons I can think that your score would continue to go up after you set `self.yourDead = true` Hopefully that helps.